# Twisted UDP to TCP Bridge

Tags: python, tcp, udp, twisted, tunnel

Recently I've taken my first stab at Twisted/Python building an app that echoes incoming UDP strings out the TCP port. I assumed this would be very simple, but I haven't been able to get it to work.  The code below is the example TCP & UDP Server modified to run together.  I'm just trying to pass some data between the two.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory, DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class TCPServer(Protocol):

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)


class UDPServer(DatagramProtocol):

    def datagramReceived(self, datagram, address):
        #This is where I would like the TCPServer's dataReceived method run passing "datagram".  I've tried: 
        TCPServer.dataReceived(datagram)
        #But of course that is not the correct call because UDPServer doesn't recognize "dataReceived"


def main():
    f = Factory()
    f.protocol = TCPServer
    reactor.listenTCP(8000, f)
    reactor.listenUDP(8000, UDPServer())
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially the frequently asked [How do I make input on one connection result in output on another?](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#HowdoImakeinputononeconnectionresultinoutputonanother)

The UDP<->TCP specifics in this question don't break the general answer given in the FAQ entry.  Just notice that a `DatagramProtocol` is easier to work with than a `Protocol` because you already have the `DatagramProtocol` instance without having to get the cooperation of a factory as you do in the `Protocol` case.

Put another way:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory, DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class TCPServer(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.port = reactor.listenUDP(8000, UDPServer(self))

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.port.stopListening()


class UDPServer(DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.stream = stream

    def datagramReceived(self, datagram, address):
        self.stream.transport.write(datagram)


def main():
    f = Factory()
    f.protocol = TCPServer
    reactor.listenTCP(8000, f)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Notice the essential change: `UDPServer` needs to call a method on an instance of `TCPServer` so it needs a reference to that instance.  This is achieved by making the `TCPServer` instance pass itself to the `UDPServer` initializer and making the `UDPServer` initializer save that reference as an attribute of the `UDPServer` instance.

Comment: I've looked at that example before but it's my understanding that the DatagramProtocol can't/doesn't use a factory.  When I tried to solve this like the example you shared I got errors that the UDPServer didn't like being referenced by the shared factory.  Said another way UDP breaks the "one connection, output on another" example.