# Echoing messages received through UDP back through a different TCP port

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp, twisted

I use Python 2.7.x (2.7.8) and am trying to write a program using twisted python to function like this:

- Program waits for a messaged received through TCP 7001 or UDP 7000.
- Messages received through UDP 7000 are bridged over to TCP 7001 going out.

I couldn't figure out how to bridge UDP to TCP, so I looked up an example on this site, like this one, [Twisted UDP to TCP Bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008281/twisted-udp-to-tcp-bridge) but the problem is that the example is lying because it doesn't work. I added a "print datagram" on datagramReceived to see if UDP responds to receiving **anything at all** and it does not. This is totally frustrating.

Here's my current test code altered **a little bit** from that example:

```html
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory, DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class TCPServer(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.port = reactor.listenUDP(7000, UDPServer(self))

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.port.stopListening()

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print "Server said:", data


class UDPServer(DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.stream = stream

    def datagramReceived(self, datagram, address):
        print datagram
        self.stream.transport.write(datagram)


def main():
    f = Factory()
    f.protocol = TCPServer
    reactor.listenTCP(7001, f)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see I changed the ports to comply with my test environment and added a print datagram to see if anything calls datagramReceived. I have no problems sending TCP things to this program, TCPServer works just fine because dataReceived can be called.

Comment: Is the idea here that incoming messages on ``UDP/7000`` are routed to connected clients on the listening server bound to ``TCP/700``?

Comment: Does it matter when the ports are different? Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. I was under the impression the example link "Bridging UDP to TCP" did that.

Comment: I'm the developer of [circuits](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/circuits) and here is what *could* work: https://gist.github.com/prologic/ae987fe4f6fbbd9ca415 -- I haven't tested this yet :)

Answer (score 3):

I ran the code from your question (with one slight modification: I enabled logging).  I used `telnet` to connect to the TCP server on port 7001.  I used a Python REPL to create a UDP socket and send some datagrams to port 7000.

Here is my REPL transcript:

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.sendto('hello', ('127.0.0.1', 7000))
5
>>> s.sendto('world', ('127.0.0.1', 7000))
5
>>>
```

Here is my server log (formatted to fit on your screen):

```
... Log opened.
... Factory starting on 7001
... Starting factory <twisted.internet.protocol.Factory instance at 0x2b9b128>
... UDPServer  starting on 7000
... Starting protocol <__main__.UDPServer instance at 0x2e8f8c0>
... hello
... world
```

And here's my telnet session transcript:

```
$ telnet localhost 7001
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
helloworld
```

My interpretation of these results is that the program actually works as specified.  I wonder what you did differently when you tried it that produced different, non-working results.